# Group of Ubuntu Servers being updated every tuesday at 7am. What triggers the update? It's not unattended-upgrades, It's not a cron job

Tags: ubuntu, update, automatic-updates

I am responsible for 5 Ubuntu Servers that all get ALL of their software updated each Tuesday at 7am. I am struggling to find out how this happens.

Security updates are applied each day through the unattended-upgrades process, but this is only security updates. Each Tuesday all installed packages are updated.

I also checked for Cron jobs for all users, but didn't find anything that answers my question.

`for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done`

I checked syslog and dkpg log, but here I can only understand that the software gets updated.. Not what/how the update is triggered.

How can I find out what triggers the update each Tuesday at 7 am?

Comment: Have you checked systemd timers?